# How do I set a sessionStorage key based on what I click in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, dom

I am trying to set a value in the sessionStorage but I am faced with a problem that how am I able to store the sessionStorage "key" differently based on what I am clicking. For example in the image below, if I were to click on the first view chat I would store a key of "1" and the  second view chat I would store a key of "2". These key value are value directly from the ajax call below. The HTML elements are cloned based on how many entries I have in the AJAX "GET" method call. Thus, each of these element (the box below) have a unique sessionStorage "key" that I would like to set when I click on that particular box's "view chat".

[image: An example will be this image where when I click on the view chat I will store a different sessionStorage "key" value from the ajax call]
**HTML File**

---

```
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">

    <!-- Default box -->
    <div class="card card-solid">
      <div class="card-body pb-0">
        <div id="chatItemBox" class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch chatItemBox">
            <div class="card bg-light">
              <div id="chatItemBoxUsername" class="card-header text-muted border-bottom-0">
                Digital Strategist
              </div>
              <div class="card-body pt-0">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-7">
                    <h2 class="lead"><b id="chatItemBoxName">Nicole Pearson</b></h2>

                    <strong><i class="fas fa-envelope mr-1"></i> Email</strong>

                    <p id="chatItemBoxEmail" class="text-muted">HI
                    </p>

                    <hr>

                    <strong><i class="fas fa-phone mr-1"></i> Contact</strong>

                    <p id="chatItemBoxContact" class="text-muted">HI
                    </p>

                    <hr>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-5 text-center">
                    <img src="../../dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-fluid">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="text-right">
                  <a href="view-chat.html" class="btn btn-sm bg-teal" onclick="sessionStorage.setItem('chatId', chatId)">
                    <i class="fas fa-comments"></i> View Chat
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
      <div class="card-footer">
        <nav aria-label="Contacts Page Navigation">
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center m-0">
            <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">8</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->

  </section>
  <!-- /.content -->  

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">

    <!-- Default box -->
    <div class="card card-solid">
      <div class="card-body pb-0">
        <div id="chatItemBox" class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch chatItemBox">
            <div class="card bg-light">
              <div id="chatItemBoxUsername" class="card-header text-muted border-bottom-0">
                Digital Strategist
              </div>
              <div class="card-body pt-0">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-7">
                    <h2 class="lead"><b id="chatItemBoxName">Nicole Pearson</b></h2>

                    <strong><i class="fas fa-envelope mr-1"></i> Email</strong>

                    <p id="chatItemBoxEmail" class="text-muted">HI
                    </p>

                    <hr>

                    <strong><i class="fas fa-phone mr-1"></i> Contact</strong>

                    <p id="chatItemBoxContact" class="text-muted">HI
                    </p>

                    <hr>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-5 text-center">
                    <img src="../../dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-fluid">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="text-right">
                  <a href="view-chat.html" class="btn btn-sm bg-teal" onclick="sessionStorage.setItem('chatId', chatId)">
                    <i class="fas fa-comments"></i> View Chat
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
      <div class="card-footer">
        <nav aria-label="Contacts Page Navigation">
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center m-0">
            <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">8</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->

  </section>
  <!-- /.content -->
```

**Script**

---

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/Retail-war/webresources/chat/retrieveChatsForUserForMerchant/' + uId,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        // Fetch the stored token from localStorage and set in the header
        headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken') },

        success: function (data) {
            // Get all chatItemBox by class
            var chatItemBox = document.getElementsByClassName('chatItemBox');

            console.log(chatItemBox)

            // Get the last one
            var lastChatItemBox = chatItemBox[chatItemBox.length - 1];

            count = 0

            $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
                var chatItemBoxUsername = document.getElementById('chatItemBoxUsername').innerHTML = entry.createdBy.username
                var chatItemBoxName = document.getElementById('chatItemBoxName').innerHTML = entry.createdBy.name
                var chatItemBoxEmail = document.getElementById('chatItemBoxEmail').innerHTML = entry.createdBy.email
                var chatItemBoxContact = document.getElementById('chatItemBoxContact').innerHTML = entry.createdBy.contactNumber

                // Clone it
                var newChatItemBox = lastChatItemBox.cloneNode(true);
                newChatItemBox.className = 'col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch chatItemBox' + count;

                count = count + 1

                console.log(newChatItemBox);

                document.getElementById('chatItemBox').appendChild(newChatItemBox)
                console.log(entry)
            })
            $('.chatItemBox').attr('id',  'toHide')
            $('#toHide').remove();
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically first parameter is the key and the second parameter is the value for sessionStorage.setItem

Use this for 1st chat window:

```
onclick="sessionStorage.setItem('1', chatId)"
```

Use this for 2nd chat window:

```
onclick="sessionStorage.setItem('1', chatId)"
```

Comment: Hello I know how sessionStorage works but I am confused on how to store different key based on the item that was click. I used cloned element thus the complication.